# If $x\geq 1$, then $x^{x^{\cos(x)}}\geq (1-\sqrt{x}+x)^{(x+1)^{\cos(x)}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

Hi it's a curious problem that I really don't understand :

> Let $x\geq 1$ then we have :
>   $$x^{x^{\cos(x)}}\geq (1-\sqrt{x}+x)^{(x+1)^{\cos(x)}}$$

It's very curious for me because the accuracy of the inequality increase when $x$ increase

But clearing the expression or taking both side logarithm we get :

$$x^{\cos(x)}\ln(x)\geq \ln(1-\sqrt{x}+x)(x+1)^{\cos(x)}$$

But it doesn't help at all to explain this mystery .

It seems that there is similarity between the graphic of $f(x)=x^n$ $n$ a natural number and $g(x)=x^{x^{\cos(x)}}- (1-\sqrt{x}+x)^{(x+1)^{\cos(x)}}$

I think furthermore that our function is quasiperiodic 
but it's too fuzzy as definition .

That's all for me If you have nice ideas it would be great .

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Comment: I think the $\cos x$ in the exponent is a distraction. Presumably $x^{x^c}\ge(x-\sqrt x+1)^{(x+1)^c}$ for all $c\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Seems that for $t=-1$ the inequality is tersest. Certainly a bummer.

Comment: Another distraction may be that square root.  In fact we have something like $$x^{x^c}\geq(x+1-\text{sth.})^{(x+1)^c}.$$  For $-1<c<0$ that sth. may be replaced by $1$.

Comment: Furthermore,  $$f(x):=x^{x^c}-(x+1-\sqrt{x})^{(x+1)^c}$$ seems to be strictly increasing for $c>0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I find interesting your comment but the last function you proposed is increasing for $1>c>0$ and $x\geq 1$

Comment: Of course, I assumed $-1<c<1$ and $x>1$ as in your question.

Comment: @ErikSatie You may improve your inequality such that the inequality is not true if replacing $\cos x$ with $1$. For example, $$x^{x^{\frac{12}{11}\cos(x)}}\geq (1-\sqrt{x}+x)^{(x+1)^{\frac{12}{11}\cos(x)}}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reducing to the Case $\boldsymbol{a=1}$**

If $a\le1$, then $\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^a\ge\frac{x}{x+1}$. Therefore, since $x\ge1$, we have
$$
x^{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^a}\ge x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}\tag1
$$
Thus, if we can show that for $x\ge1$,
$$
x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}\ge x-\sqrt{x}+1\tag2
$$
then inequality $(1)$ says that for $a\le1$,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x^{x^a}\ge\left(x-\sqrt{x}+1\right)^{(x+1)^a}}\tag3
$$

---

**Proving the Case $\boldsymbol{a=1}$**

Substituting $x\mapsto x^2$ in $(2)$, we see that, for $x\ge1$, showing $(2)$ is equivalent to showing
$$
x^2\log\left(x^2\right)\ge\left(1+x^2\right)\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)\tag4
$$
That is, inequality $(4)$ shows inequality $(3)$.

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
&x^2\log\left(x^2\right)-\left(1+x^2\right)\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)\\
&=x^2\log\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2-x+1}\right)-\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)\\
&=-x^2\log\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)-\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)\\
&\ge x^2\left(\frac{x-1}{x^2}+\frac12\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^4}+\frac13\frac{(x-1)^3}{x^6}+\frac14\frac{(x-1)^4}{x^8}\right)-\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)\\
&=x-\frac12-\frac2{3x}-\frac1{4x^2}+\frac7{6x^4}-\frac1{x^5}+\frac1{4x^6}-\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
The derivative of the right side of $(5)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
&1+\frac2{3x^2}+\frac1{2x^3}-\frac{14}{3x^5}+\frac5{x^6}-\frac3{2x^7}-\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}\\
&=\frac{(x-1)^3\left(6x^6-2x^4-x^3+4x^2-12x+9\right)}{6x^7\left(x^2-x+1\right)}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
For $x\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
&6x^6-2x^4-x^3+4x^2-12x+9\\
&=6(x-1)^6+36(x-1)^5+88(x-1)^4+111(x-1)^3\\
&\phantom{=}\ +79(x-1)^2+21(x-1)+4\\
&\ge4\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(6)$ and $(7)$ show that the right hand side of $(5)$ is increasing for $x\ge1$. This verifies $(4)$ since the right hand side of $(5)$ is $0$ for $x=1$. Thus, we have proven $(3)$.

$\Large\square$

---

**Closeness of the Inequality**

Consider the Taylor series for $x^2\log\left(x^2\right)-\left(1+x^2\right)\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)$ near $x=1$. Let $x=1+u$, then look at the Taylor series
$$
\begin{align}
&x^2\log\left(x^2\right)-\left(1+x^2\right)\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)\\
&=2\left(1+2u+u^2\right)\log(1+u)-\left(2+2u+u^2\right)\log\left(1+u+u^2\right)\\
&=2\left(1+2u+u^2\right)\left(u-\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}3-\frac{u^4}4+\frac{u^5}5-\frac{u^6}6+\frac{u^7}7+O\!\left(u^8\right)\right)\\
&\phantom{=}\ -\left(2+2u+u^2\right)\left(u+\frac12u^2-\frac23u^3+\frac14u^4+\frac15u^5-\frac26u^6+\frac{u^7}7+O\!\left(u^8\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{u^4}6-\frac{u^5}6-\frac{u^6}{60}+\frac{u^7}5+O\!\left(u^8\right)\\
&=\frac{(x-1)^4}6-\frac{(x-1)^5}6-\frac{(x-1)^6}{60}+\frac{(x-1)^7}5+O\!\left((x-1)^8\right)\tag8
\end{align}
$$
The series in $(8)$ shows why the inequality is very close when $x\sim1$.

The asymptotic series in $(5)$ shows that as $x\to\infty$, we have
$$
x^2\log\left(x^2\right)-\left(1+x^2\right)\log\left(x^2-x+1\right)=x-2\log(x)-\frac12+O\!\left(\frac1x\right)\tag9
$$
which shows that as $x\to\infty$,
$$
\frac{x^x}{\left(x-\sqrt{x}+1\right)^{x+1}}=\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{x\sqrt{e}}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right)\tag{10}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

It suffices to prove that
$$x^{\cos x}\ln x \ge (x+1)^{\cos x}\ln (1 - \sqrt{x} + x)$$
which is written as
$$ \ln x
\ge \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{\cos x}\ln (1 - \sqrt{x} + x). $$
It suffices to prove that
$$ \ln x
\ge \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)\ln (1 - \sqrt{x} + x). $$
It suffices to prove that
$$ x\ln x
\ge (x+1)\ln (1 - \sqrt{x} + x). $$
Let $f(x) = x\ln x - (x+1)\ln (1 - \sqrt{x} + x)$. We have
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \ln \frac{x}{1 - \sqrt{x} + x} - \frac{x-1}{2(1 - \sqrt{x} + x)\sqrt{x}}\\
&\ge \frac{2(\frac{x}{1 - \sqrt{x} + x}-1)}{\frac{x}{1 - \sqrt{x} + x}+1}
 - \frac{x-1}{2(1 - \sqrt{x} + x)\sqrt{x}}\\
&= \frac{(2\sqrt{x} - 1)(\sqrt{x} - 1)^3}{2(1 - \sqrt{x} + x)\sqrt{x}(2x + 1 - \sqrt{x})}\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}
where we have used $\ln u \ge \frac{2(u-1)}{u+1}$ for all $u \ge 1$ (Note:
$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} u}(\ln u - \frac{2(u-1)}{u+1}) = \frac{(u-1)^2}{u(u+1)^2}$).
Also, $f(1) = 0$. Thus, $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\ge 1$.

We are done.